# Write in txt file, edit, display in JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

How do I:

**Write in .txt file:** Automatically create 100 blank records (fields: record id,name,age,etc) in a .txt file at the start of the program. Record id wont be blank

**edit:** I will enter a record id (ranging from 1-100) to add or edit data to the blank record, record id cant be edited

**display in `JOptionPane`:** I will enter a record id and all corresponding data will be displayed in `JOptionPane` (I know how to use `JOptionPane` to display stuff, but i dont know how to display only the selected data from a .txt file)

Can anyone please help to me how to do a program like this? 
I know java, but im still a noob.

ok so far this is what I've got. no idea what to do next

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class writer {
public void writing() {
    try {
        File Text = new File(filepath here);
        FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream(Text);
        OutputStreamWriter OSW = new OutputStreamWriter(FOS);    
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(OSW);
        for(int x=1;x<101;x++){
        w.write("Account #"+x);
        }w.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem writing to the file!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    writer write = new writer();
    write.writing();
}
}
```

Comment: For only 100 record, you can just create a map with id being the key. If a file exists, read the file and store it in a map. You can edit it when you need to. To show, find the key in the map and display its contents. Start like this and show some code that you tried and then we'll help you out.

Comment: Why do you want to use .txt file? Is this requirement ? You could java Map for this.

Comment: yes the .txt file thingy is a requirement

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this sounds a lot like homework, so I'll give you some pointers which should hopefully allow you to find the results yourself with some directed searching...

Depending on how much data you wish to put in the .txt file, you might want to edit it by hand, in a CSV format:

`accountId,name,age,etc`

You are looking to have 100 records - while you can do it this way, you could start with just a handful created by hand, as an initial step, before writing something to produce your records.

After that, you need to design your model (ie. the Account object), this is likely to be a Plain Old Java Object (POJO), which is a standard class, with some private attributes, and getters and setters to access the data stored within.

You'll also need to read in the source data file and turn them into (Account) objects that will be later used - in instances like this, I like to use the `BufferedReader` class, as it allows you to read in an entire line of a text file in one go:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new (File("/path/to/file")))));`

You are then able to read in a line of the file with `String line = reader.readLine()`

Look at the methods available in the `String` class to see if you can find a suitable method to break up a string, based on a given separating value (in this case a comma, since it's csv) - you then create a new Account object and populate it with the values provided.

Several people have (rightly) pointed out the use of a `Map` to store the created objects - Hint: Look up `HashMap` (the account id can be the key)

When it comes to getting input from the user, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` will be what you need (parentComponent can be `null`)

I hope that is enough to get you going, without actually completing your homework for you.
If you have more questions, feel free to ask away.